# Logging in Custom Jar in Jasper reports

Tags: jar, jasper-reports, log4j, jasperserver, jaspersoft-studio

I have included a custom jar for one of my jasper reports and it is working fine.Now for debugging purposes I want to implement log4j/slf4j in my classes in this custom jar so that when report is previewed in Jaspersodt Studio or run on JasperSoft server i can see the logging statements in a file.

Right now I have added all configuration but loggers are not printing in the file.My guess is that log4j is not getting triggered.

**1)Is there any more setting/configuration is required?**

**2) I checked Jaspersoft server has default implementation for log4j and it logs but only various queries.Is there any particular setting/logger to set so that it includes custom jar loggers as well?**
Below log4j.properties is put into resources folder of my maven project(custom jar)

```
  log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file


  log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
  log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
  log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
  log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n


  log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
  log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\log4j-application.log
  log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
  log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
  log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
  log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

EDIT: 
Below is Java code.This is exported in a jar and added in classpath in my jasper project.When I preview my report chart is created and this customizer is excuted but I do not see any log statements in the file I have given in log4j.properties above :

```
public class BarChartDemo {
static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(BarChartDemo.class);
   public void customize(JFreeChart chart, JRChart jasperChart) {
             LOGGER.debug("debug");
             LOGGER.info("info");
             LOGGER.warn("warn");
             LOGGER.error("error");
             ?/customizer code
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can anyone help me out on this please?

Comment: could you add the java code of your custom class where the logging is produced? what kind of log do you expect to see? Thanks

Comment: @Gianluca - I have added the java code

Comment: Can anyone help me on this please...